# How to get a list of fields from many to many relationships in entityframework core?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I try to get a list from field text at tag tables.

I'm using C#, and asp.net core.
My relationships are many-to-many with a join-table.
How do I get a text at tag tables ?

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }

    public string AdditionalInfo {get;set;}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PostTag> PostTags {get;set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True");

}
```

The program below gives me a wrong result.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new MyContext();
        int _Id = 1;

        var texts = context.Posts
                .Include(p => p.PostTags)
                    .ThenInclude( p => p.Tag)
                .Where( p => p.Id == _Id )
                .Select( p => p.PostTags.Select( pt => pt.Tag).Select( t => t.Text))
                .ToList();

        foreach (var text in texts) {
              Console.WriteLine($" Element # {text}");
         }

    }

}
```

The result is :

```
Element # System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer],System.String]
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining all three tables on respective ids and selecting tags table text column will give you the required output.

```
          var texts = from p in context.Posts
            join pt in context.PostTags on p.Id equals pt.PostId
            join tag in context.Tags on pt.TagId equals tag.Id
            select tag.Text;

            foreach (var text in texts)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine($" Element # {text}");
            }
```